# How to display data in gridview in popup in aspx and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, popup

I have been created loginfo button for display details.

I need to display details in popup,

May i know how to create source code for popup to display details.?

Here is my click event code loginfo:

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Logrow")
                {
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_logdetails", con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Redirect("library.aspx");
                }
```

and sp_logdetails:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_logdetails
(
@bookid int
)
AS
begin
select * from book_lending where bookid = @bookid
end
```

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Book_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="240px" 
        Width="755px" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="2px">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log Info">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnloginfo" Text="Log-Info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Book_id") %>' CommandName="Logrow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
              <ControlStyle BackColor="#FF0066" ForeColor="White" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When i execute above query, it works fine,

Here is the screenshot of executed query, http://s23.postimg.org/ob79r2o6z/untitled1.jpg

Can anyone help me to display the book-details in front end as popup.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

I referred this http://jqueryasp.net/show-gridview-popup-window-asp-net/ but i just confused with calling stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

1) For popup you can use AJAX Control Toolkit. Have a look on below tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663896/Popup-Control-for-ASP-NET

2) You can also use JQuery Ajax to fetch the data on client side and display in JQuery popup or bootstrap popups.

Comment: yes.. i already seen the above links, I'm new to .net and all.. so i just confused with code. can you please help ? thanks

Comment: There is enough details is available in tutorials, tried it. Also look to use JQuery Ajax to fetch data on client side and show in popup.

Comment: in this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663896/Popup-Control-for-ASP-NET what is DDL?

Comment: That is actually DLL not DDL. you will first add the reference of DLL of ajax control tookil to use it.

Comment: may i know, how to add DLL toolkit?

Comment: 1) You can add it by adding reference in project. 2) using packet manager console you can install by using this command    Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99680/discussion-between-rani-and-muhammad-danish).